# How can I get a text in html code using the Selenium?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

I want to get players name on the https://www.premierleague.com/match/22720.

HTML code :

'Player Name' = each player on the website

```
<div class="info"><span class="name">'Player Name'<div class="playerLineupEventContainer-4664"></div></span>
```

My code :

```
match_players = match_player_wd.find_elements_by_class_name('info')

len(match_players) = 36
```

I just need 11 players name of 'Tottenham'. But I don't know how to get names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two type of players :

1. Home Player.
2. Away Player.

You can try with this code to get players name :

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = r'driver_path')
wait = WebDriverWait(driver,10)

driver.maximize_window()

driver.get("https://www.premierleague.com/match/22720")

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.scoreboxContainer')))

home_players = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div.home div.event')

for home_player in home_players:
  print(home_player.text)

away_players = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div.away div.event')

for away_player in away_players:
  print(away_player.text)
```

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try the following:

```
player_elem = match_player_wd.find_elements_by_class_name('name')
player_names = [e.text for e in player_elem]
```

I did not take a look at the source of the page, so it may not be as direct as just selecting all elements with the "name" class. In that case, you probably need to set the 'info' class element as the root first and fetch its children by the same `find_by_class_name()` function.